# This is my code, where I have parsed the `XML` data for latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode

This is my code, where I have parsed the `XML` data for latitude and longitude.

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"result"])
{
    [inputArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictTempDataStorage]];

}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
{
    [dictTempDataStorage setObject:[NSString stringWithString:foundValue] forKey:@"name"];
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"vicinity"])
{
    [dictTempDataStorage setObject:[NSString stringWithString:foundValue] forKey:@"vicinity"];
}

else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lat"])
{
    [dictTempDataStorage setObject:[NSString stringWithString:foundValue] forKey:@"latitude"];

}

else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lng"])
{
    [dictTempDataStorage setObject:[NSString stringWithString:foundValue] forKey:@"long"];
}
[foundValue setString:@""];
```

}

Comment: Why did you untick my answer?

Comment: Subrat Padhi tell the reason

Comment: Accidentally :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the lat,long value into dictionary

```
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lat"])
{
     NSNumber *numberLat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:foundValue];
     NSString *strLat = [numberLat stringValue];
     [dictTempDataStorage setObject:strLat forKey:@"latitude"];
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lng"])
{
    NSNumber *numberLong = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:foundValue];
    NSString *strLong = [numberLong stringValue];
    [dictTempDataStorage setObject:strLong forKey:@"long"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[dictTempDataStorage setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",foundValue] forKey:@"long"];